# Getting the memory status of the linux OS to display on the web application

Tags: reactjs, linux, api, debian, dashboard

I need to track the memory usage of my linux operating system through web application. In the application I want to display the memory utilization and the avilable free memory. Is there an any API that I can make use of that gives me the status. How this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Springboot Application and expose the Memory Usage data as a Rest Api.
There are though better solutions like Prometheus and Grafana. You could take a look at

MONITORING LINUX HOST METRICS WITH THE NODE EXPORTER which exposes an api as http://localhost:9100/metrics. And then you could consume it either through your React webapp or throug a Prometheus deployment. Grafana has really cool out of the box Dashboards that are worth taking in consideration.